# How can I allow more file extensions with file uploads?

Tags: 7, files

I've got a module that let users upload files, and everything works as long as the files are in the standard array of allowed extensions. I've tried using [`file_validate_extensions()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--file.inc/function/file_validate_extensions), but this doesn't seem to change anything.

This is the code I'm using to upload now (the docx extension is added to the standard allowed ones, but it doesn't seem to get picked up):

```
$fid = $form_state['values']['attachment'];
$file = file_load($fid);

if ($file != null) {
  file_validate_extensions($file, "jpg jpeg gif png txt doc xls pdf ppt pps odt ods odp docx");
  $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
  file_save($file);
}
```

Comment: Hello, Slyder; welcome on _Drupal Answers_. This is not the answer to your question, but you are not using the value returned from `file_validate_extensions()`; as the function just checks if the extension is one of the extensions contained in the string passed as argument, and it returns an array containing an error string, if you don't use the returned value is perfectly useless to call the function.

Answer (score 2):

You actually have to check for the return values of the [file_validate_extensions()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/path_to_theme/7) function in order to detect if any errors have occurred.

so your code would be something like this:

```
$fid = $form_state['values']['attachment'];
$file = file_load($fid);

if ($file != null) {
  $extension_errors=file_validate_extensions($file, "jpg jpeg gif png txt doc xls pdf ppt pps odt ods odp docx");
  if (!$extension_errors) {
  $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
  file_save($file);
  } else form_set_error('attachment',$extension_errors[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is here

[drupal-7-handling-file-uploads](http://blog.ryantan.net/2011/04/drupal-7-handling-file-uploads/)

[Drupal 7 forms API: File not uploading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11017915/1877909)

I too have tried with below form and it worked for me

```
function video_upload_subtitles_form($form, &$form_state) {
     $form['sub_file'] = array(
            '#type' => 'file',
            '#title' => t('Upload video'),
            '#description' => t('Pick a video file to upload.'),
        );

}
function video_upload_subtitles_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
 $validators = array('file_validate_extensions' => array());
 $file = file_save_upload('sub_file', $validators, "public://");
}
```